# Как сделать Redirect после регистрации

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребята помоги сделать редирект. Как user увидеть сообщение: Вы успешно зарегистрированы! чтобы после 5 секунд его перекинуло на index.php

```
{
    $("#block-form-registration").fadeOut(300,function() {
        $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_good").fadeIn(400).html("Вы успешно зарегистрированы!");
        $("#form_submit").hide();
    });

} else {
   $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_error").fadeIn(400).html(data); 
}
```

Comment: `document.location.href = "/index.php"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 setTimeout("document.location.href='http://ssilka.ru'", 5000);
```

**Обновление**

```
{
 $("#block-form-registration").fadeOut(300,function() { 
   $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_good").fadeIn(400).h‌​tml("Вы успешно зарегистрированы!"); 
   $("#form_submit").hide();
   setTimeout("document.location.href='yapoki.ru'";, 5000);
 });

} else { 
  $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_error").fadeIn(400).‌​html(data); 
}
```

Comment: Я попробовал что то не получается, не могли бы подсказать куда именно это писать?

Comment: То что надо спасибо!